# Pandas: replace some values in column if that contain a substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
member_id,device_type,device_id,event_type,event_path,event_duration
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,3,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/community.livejournal.com/psp_ru,28,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
```

And I should find substring from another file and if it contain pattrn, create a column `category` from `find.xlsx`

```
url category    category2
falloutsite.ru/ Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/    Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/ 
kmzpub.ru/games.asp Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/  Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/ 
sigma-team.ru/content/view/15/19    Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Quake и Counter-Strike/     Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Quake и Counter-Strike/ 
community.livejournal.com/psp_ru    Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочные игры/     Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочные игры/
```

I use

```
df = pd.read_csv('car owners games_category.csv')
find = pd.read_excel('blue.xlsx')
d = find.set_index('url')['category'].to_dict()
df['category'] = df.device_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x]))
```

to replace that to category, but it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.
I try to use `map` and `isin`, but it need common string.

Comment: Could you please put some time into making your data [clipboard friendly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time testing with real data there is problem `Series` from list comprehension return 2 category, not one in row `13`.

One posible solution is use `iloc[0]` for return only first item from `Series`:

```
df['category'] = df.device_id
                   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x]).iloc[0])
```

Another solution is remove this row by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
find.drop(13, inplace=True)
```

Testing all problematic rows:

```
#custom function return list to column 'category'
def f(x):
    return [v for k,v in d.items() if k in x]
df['category'] = df.device_id.apply(f)
print (df)

#filter all rows where length of list is not 1
print (df[df.category.apply(len) != 1])

#return length of problematic rows
print (df.ix[df.category.apply(len) != 1, 'category'].apply(len))
```